# who work SSL provider and how I create SSL/TLS service povider like certum , comodo and digicert

Tags: security, ssl, openssl

how I can create a SSL/TLS provider like comodo , let's encrypt , etc , how work this process , security companies like comodo how generate a SSl certificate and how validate ssl/tls certificate , and where is keeping SSL/TLS public key .

Comment: This question is to broad to be answered. Please focus a bit more.

Comment: in basic question who work ssl service provider

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/